# Include custom JavaScript in the app.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, assets

I want to include a custom JavaScript in the app.js file which as the following code:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

The require only works for published packages and using node install but I want to know if there is a way to include a custom js in this file in order to have just one built script in my app (in this case the app.js script).

Answer (score 7):

Add your scripts under this path `\resources\assets\js\`,

(ex : `\resources\assets\js\scripts\my_script.js` & `\resources\assets\js\another_script.js`)

And, add them to `\resources\assets\js\app.js`

```
require ('./scripts/my_script.js');
require ('./another_script.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your script in `resources/assets/js` and then run `gulp` to compile all your scripts into `app.js`
[Check this for more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#webpack)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have other files that are not exactly VueJs files and you want to build into a single script. In that case it is not good to put the script in that file. You can however place the files in your `resources/assets/js` folder and add some code to your `gulpfile.js` to build all your scripts into one file. Here is the code you might need to add.

```
 mix.scripts([
   'filename.js',
 ]);
```

By default, the build file will be placed in `public/js/all.js`.

You can customise that driectory by modifying the example above to something like this

```
mix.scripts([
  'filename.js
], 'path/to/file.js');
```